# Imacros help, script was working but not now

Tags: imacros

This line was working before but now it doesn't extract the text, I guess this is happening because it is clicking inside the box. This only happen when I use Firefox, using Internet Explorer is ok.

```
VERSION BUILD=8021970
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:emailForm ATTR=ID:fName&&VALUE:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the value you need is disappear when imacros tries to scrape it, but you can use this code to get email:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/ 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span attr=id:cxtEmail EXTRACT=TXT
```

or you can scrape htm of your tag and parse it to get value attribute

Comment: didnt notice that one, Thanks you very much, appreciated it.